# HTML5 role attribute for tags

Tags: html, tags, wai-aria

My HTML5 template has `h1` elements on every page (that I use for keyword) on top left part of the page.

Is there a `role` attribute to sign them as tags like the tags in WorPress?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: If you are using `h1` to mean "Some keywords" instead of "The most important heading on the page", then you are using it wrong.

Comment: but I know that it is recommended to use h1s on a page several times for html5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined by W3C, you can use this values for `role` attribute:

- `banner`
- `complementary`
- `contentinfo`
- `definition`
- `main`
- `navigation`
- `note`
- `search`

`contentinfo` purpose is to provide meta information about the content, so it could be used for tag management. That said, `<h1>` shouldn't be used as tags, as it's main purpose is to explicitly describe the whole page

[Source](http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#XHTMLRoleModule)

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of all WAI-ARIA roles in the *WAI-ARIA 1.0* specification:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-wai-aria-20140320/roles#role_definitions

There doesn’t seem to be a role for tags. The [`contentinfo` role](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-wai-aria-20140320/roles#contentinfo) could be used for the element that contains all tags the current document is tagged with.

In HTML5, `contentinfo` is the default role for the [`footer` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-footer-element), which is the element you [should use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31475654/1591669) for tags anyhow (instead of `h1`, which would typically be not correct). You might be interested in my related [answer about semantic markup for tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16242043/1591669).