# Valid role attribute values for h1 element

Tags: html, wai-aria

(I already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545030/html5-role-attribute-for-tags) and the attributes linked do not work for me.)

I have a `h1` tag containing a dropdown which activates onclick. The W3C Validator is complaining here:

```
  <h1 class='dropdown-toggle' id='mylist' 
         data-toggle='dropdown'
         aria-haspopup='true'
         aria-expanded='true' 
         role='button'>
```

Apparently a `role='button'` can't be assigned to `h1`. Now the question is: which role can I assign to a `h1`? The W3C's long list of role attributes does not really help finding a solution.

[Test page](http://www.lyra.net/canzoni-e-accordi/fabrizio-de-andre/volume-i/preghiera-in-gennaio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to find out which WAI-ARIA roles an HTML5 element can have:

1. Go the HTML5 specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/
2. Check the ToC’s section 4 for the link to the element’s definition: [The `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, and `h6` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements)
3. Check this element’s "Allowed ARIA role attribute values":

   > `heading` role (default - do not set), `tab` or `presentation`.

Answer (score 2):

Since HTML5 was published, in Oct 2014, the rules for use of ARIA in HTML have been moved into a [separate specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/) (a module of the HTML spec). The rules are still summarised in each element definition in the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/).
In the case of `h1-h6 elements` the [rules are detailed](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#h1-h6) (along with those of all other HTML elements) in the [conformance table in ARIA in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance).

[Notes on using ARIA in HTML](http://w3c.github.io/aria-in-html/) may also be helpful in understanding the why and how of ARIA use in HTML.