# Can I use <nav> tag for list of article tags?

Tags: html, nav, semantic-markup

After the article I have list of tags related to article. Is it semantically correct to wrap list of those tags in `<nav>` html tag? If no, what would be the proper one?

```
<nav class="tags">
    Tags:
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Tag1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tag2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tag3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[MDN states:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav)

1. Not all links of a document must be in a `<nav>` element, which is
   intended only for major block of navigation links; typically the
   `<footer>` element often has a list of links that don't need to be in a
   `<nav>` element.
2. User agents, such as screen readers targeting disabled users, can
   use    this element to determine whether to omit the initial
   rendering of    this content.

Comment: The article is tagged with these tags, correct? (Or are these just related tags, which the article is not tagged with?)

Comment: @unor yes, article is tagged with them

Answer (score 1):

The `<nav>` tag defines a set of navigation links.

Notice that NOT all links of a document should be inside a `<nav>` element. The `<nav>` element is intended only for major block of **navigation links**.

Browsers, such as screen readers for disabled users, can use this element to determine whether to omit the initial rendering of this content.

Answer (score 1):

The tags are part of the article’s metadata (just like the author name, the publication date, etc.), so they should be in a [`footer` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-footer-element), and this `footer` should be inside the `article` element:

```html
<article>
  <footer><!-- tags --></footer>
</article>
```

(Some might use [`header`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-header-element) instead of `footer`, but its default role `banner` is not really appropriate, and it can’t have the `contentinfo` role, [which would be appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33056298/1591669).)

For such a simple list of tags, another sectioning element isn’t really needed.

Related: my answer about [semantic markup for tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16242043/1591669).