# Multiple occurences of same itemprop in Microdata schema.org

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

I tested My microdata schema.org on google:

The google tools did not return any error...

```
**Item** 
    type:   http://schema.org/webpage
    property:   
    url:    http://127.0.0.1/
    image:  http://127.0.0.1/design/logo.jpg
    datemodified:   2014-03-05 20:12:56
    text:   
    Item 1
    breadcrumb: Skip to content
    text:   
    Item 2



    **Item 1**
    type:   http://schema.org/wpheader
    property:   
    url:    http://127.0.0.1
    headline:   website name
    image:  http://127.0.0.1/design/logo.jpg
    description:    some text


    **Item 2**
    type:   http://schema.org/sitenavigationelement
```

You can see I used multiple itemprop="text" for the webpage type...

Is it valid?

If yes you know itemprop="url" for WebPage type is invalid... or itemListElement for ItemList is valid. How can I recognize which itemprop is valid and which one is invalid?

----------------///EDIT///-------------------

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/webpage">
<body>
<div itemprop="text" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/wpheader">
...
</div>

<div itemprop="text" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're not getting an error why do you question its validity?

Comment: becuase use double itemprop="url" for one WebPage type  is invalid but google lab do not return any error!

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you are asking exactly. Is your question if it’s allowed to have the same property several times in the same item?

Comment: Thanks dear unor...I read 'http://schema.org/WebPage'...I thank it muse be true...like one of your answer to me about itemList

Comment: @user3307827: I still don’t understand your question(s). Could you try to rephrase them?

Comment: @unor I edited my post and add the source code. Can I use multi itemprop="text" form one type?

Comment: I didn't get any error from google lab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have the same property several times for the same item (for example, to [specify Schema.org’s `name` in different languages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21365575/1591669)). But note that [Microdata doesn’t define what it should mean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21239191/1591669) when there is the same property more than one time specified.

So something like this is totally fine:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <body>
    <div itemprop="text">…</div>
    <div itemprop="text">…</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

(Note that there may be a problem with your specific example: Schema.org’s [`text` property](http://schema.org/text) expects *Text*, but you are using another item as value. It’s not forbidden, though.)

(Also note that the case matters, so it has to be `http://schema.org/WPHeader` instead of `http://schema.org/wpheader`. Same with `http://schema.org/WebPage`.)

Comment: So according to your answer If I changed <div> tag in your example to <div itemprop="text" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">,it is correct!right?

Comment: @user3307827: That’s hard to answer. This is correct Microdata, yes. But Schema.org wants you to use a value consisting of text here, and not (like in your example) a value consisting of another type (`SiteNavigationElement`). But it’s probably not an error (see ["Expected types" on schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#schemaorg_expected)). It’s an *expected* (and not a *required*) type after all. So yes, you may probably use it like that.