# 2 itemprops for 2 colors of the same product?

Tags: microdata, schema.org

In a product with two colors, is it better to use two `itemprop` items or just one?

```html
<meta itemprop="color" content="red" />
<meta itemprop="color" content="black" />
```

Or

```html
<meta itemprop="color" content="red and black" />
```

I am using https://schema.org/ vocabulary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Microdata perspective, both ways are possible. The difference is that you are adding [two values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22337572/1591669) in the first case, and one value in the second case.

From the Schema.org perspective, we’d have to understand how this property was meant to be used. The description of [`color`](http://schema.org/color) says:

> The color of the product.

It uses singular here, so this could be a hint for using your first example. But it uses "The color" and not "A color", which might suggest that they only thought of cases where a product has only one (primary) color.

I think it makes more sense to use several `color` properties. When using an own property for each value, consumers wouldn’t have to parse your string (possibly containing several colors) and trying to extract each color.

The only time I’d consider using one property containing several colors would be when I consider it to be "a new color containing other colors", so to say.

Oh, and just to be sure: Your markup would mean that one product is red *and* black, and *not* that you have the product available in red *or* in black.

Comment: "a new color containing other colors"? Excuse me, but don't understand what you want to say. In my case the products are soccer t-shirts and they might be single color or many colors... then how do you do it to markup?

Comment: @mdromed: In general, I’d **use your first example**, also for t-shirts. -- This "new color containing other colors" thing was just meant to be a possible reason for using your second example, but it’s rather philosophical (i.e., in cases where you’d say that it *is* only one color and this color has the name "red-and-black", so to say).

Comment: ah, ok, i understand. In italian soccer "rossonero" for example mean rosso=red and nero=black.  Perfect. Thanks a lot for your help friend!