# Article page with multiple itemprop="articleBody" attributes?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

When structuring an article page with Microdata tags [(schema.org/Article)](http://schema.org/Article), is it possible to have multiple sections with `itemprop="articleBody"` or is only one occurence allowed?

In my case I have an Article page that have both a Preamble and a Main body part, which are separated in different div:s with other content in between. So the easiest solution for me would be to have  two `itemprop="articleBody"` attributes, one for each part. Is that possible ?

```html
<div itemprop="articleBody" class="article-preamble>
    <p>Article preamble lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<div class="related-articles> 
    <!-- This div's content should not be a part of itemprop="articleBody" -->
    <a href=#">Related article 1...</a>
</div>

<div itemprop="articleBody" class="article-body-text>
    <p>Article main body text... lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: how do you get an articel with two preambles and bodyies? Logically that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: No the Article consists of only one Preamble and one Main body text, but they are separated. The Preamble field is often used in teasers that link to the Articles.

Comment: Ah now I get it. When I get schema.org right, than it is not possible since they expect preamble and main part in the articleBody.

Comment: But in the end you can test it with: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Comment: Yes that true, thanks, I'll give it a shoot and see what Google thinks about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple occurences of same itemprop in Microdata schema.org](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330275/multiple-occurences-of-same-itemprop-in-microdata-schema-org)

Comment: Yes unor, might be close to a duplicate, but slightly differnt since this was more specific (itemprop="articleBody"). Also I think duplicates are good since different askers will phrase their questions differently, just as people who will search for the same issue later will. So the duplicates will help some people who might search on a different term in the future to find their answer. So I don't think you should avoid asking questions even though someone already asked a almost similar question before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike, you can use multiple identical properties for certain schemas, but for a type such as an article, you really should only have one articleBody.  Google's tool will not display error messages for all errors, as it's not advanced enough to detect all technical errors.  Unfortunately, schema.org/Article does not have an exact-match property to use for a preamble, but a property that might be suitable to use is the "description" property.

Comment: Thanks David, the description field seems like a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google Webmaster Tools, seems to allow multiple itemprop:s when I try to validate it:

[image]