# Multiple headline for an Article

Tags: data-structures, schema.org, microdata

I have an `Article` schema for my structured data. I've three part of title like "Up title", "Main Title" and "Lead":

```
<section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <h2 itemprop="name">
     This is up title
  </h2>

  <h1 itemprop="headline">
     This is up title
  </h1>

  <h3 itemprop="about">
     This is lead
  </h3>
```

Which property should I use for each title?

And is there any limitation for using multiple of the same property like two or more `headline` in my example?

Comment: I dont see any limitation for duplicate property on schema.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may [use a property multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22337572/1591669).

For `Article`, you have several options for the different kinds of names and titles:

- every `Thing` can have [`name`](http://schema.org/name) and [`alternateName`](http://schema.org/alternateName)
- every `CreativeWork` can have [`headline`](http://schema.org/headline) and [`alternativeHeadline`](http://schema.org/alternativeHeadline)

Sometimes something is used as a title, but it’s actually something else (in addition), e.g. an additional title containing a section name (like "Sports", "Politics" etc.) could use [`articleSection`](http://schema.org/articleSection), an additional title containing the topic the article is about (like "Bitcoin", "Programming" etc.) could use [`about`](http://schema.org/about).